# Assign 10 letters evenly to 200 letters

Tags: r

I have 10 letters "a b c d e f g h i j" and 200 numbers from 1 to 200 with different number of instances, e.g. five 1s three 2s etc. making up 200 numbers in total.

I would like to assign each number a letter such that each letter has equal frequency.

So in this case I want 20 instances of each letter.

My problem is that I would like to **randomly** assign letters to numbers.

An example would be:

```
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 ...until 200

a a a a a e e f f f f f f d i j c c c ...until 200
```

Comment: Can you reporduce an example of your data, please? and produce by the way an example of the result that you expect.

Comment: I've edited the question, I can't provide sample data but I hope its clear now, I also have the expected result as an illustration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this-- I'm deliberately not overwriting the existing column in `A`

```
Rgames> B<-sample(letters,10)
Rgames> B
 [1] "b" "m" "l" "v" "c" "t" "s" "i" "n" "j"
Rgames> A<-sample(1:10,10,replace=TRUE)
Rgames> A
 [1] 3 3 2 8 1 5 5 8 2 6
Rgames> A.new<-B[A]
Rgames> A.new
 [1] "l" "l" "m" "i" "b" "c" "c" "i" "m" "t"
```

Then you could `cbind` if desired to combine `A.new` and `A`

Comment: thanks for your help, I'm not quite sure what this does. I've edited the question to make it more comprehensible. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I think I did exactly what you wanted: picked a random letter (tho' you now wanted a number, it's the same thing) and applied it everywhere a certain value showed up in `A` .  If you're having trouble interpreting things like  `B[A]` then you should read the introductory tutorials on the R language.

Comment: yes this is a great solution, the only problem is that I would like to have the letters equally distributed. so for example I have 200 from A and 10 from B then have 200/10 for each value in B assigned to A