# Randomly choose value between 1 and 10 with equal number of instances

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select and insert value unique number of times in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721050/select-and-insert-value-unique-number-of-times-in-r)

I would like to generate 2000 random numbers between 1 and 10 such that for each random number I have the same number of instances.

In this case 200 for each number.

What should be random is the order in which it is generated.

I have the following problem:

I have an array with 2000 entries but not each with unique values, for example it starts like this:

```
11112233333333344445667777777777
```

and consists of 2000 entries.

I would like to generate random numbers and assign each UNIQUE value a separate random number but have an entry for each value

So my intended result would look like this:

```
original array: 11112233333333344445667777777777
random numbers: 33334466666666699991778888888888
```

Comment: I think the best method for this would be to populate the array with the values you want, randomize the array, then whenever a "random" call is made, shift a value from the front or pop a value from the end and return it.

Comment: Wouldn't you only get 200 random numbers if you only have 1-10 and 20 of each?

Comment: the problem is that I'm trying to assign these numbers to a pre-existing array. for example I have an array with 1111 2 2 33 444 values then I generate random numbers between 1 and 10 and I want the same random numbers to be assigned to identical values in the above array.

Comment: Then maybe provide example input and output because it's not clear to me what you want.

Comment: It's bad form to re-ask the same question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721050/select-and-insert-value-unique-number-of-times-in-r/13723230#13723230 ) rather than edit the first question to represent what you want.

Comment: FWIW, the answer @CarlWitthoft provided you in the question he linked is better than all of these in my opinion...

Answer (score 6):

You could do this in a few steps:

```
my_numbers <- rep(1:10, each=200)
my_randomizer <- sample(seq_along(my_numbers), length(my_numbers))

my_random_numbers <- my_numbers[my_randomizer]
```

---

Based on the edits:

I would use `rle`.  It sounds like you don't have an array, but instead a vector:

```
my_array_rled <- rle(my_array)

my_random_numbers <- sample(1:10, length(unique(my_array)))

my_array_rled$values <- factor(my_array_rled$values)
levels(my_array_rled$values) <- my_random_numbers

my_array_randomized <- inverse.rle(my_array_rled)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I've edited the question to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can use "rep" to replicate your random numbers 200 times and "sample" to randomize the resulting vector.

```
x <- sample(rep(runif(2000,1,10),200))
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I've edited the question, it wasn't clear what I'm asking for

Answer (score 0):

A non vectorized code:

```
# using a seed for reproducible example
set.seed(2)

original_array <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7)
random_numbers <- numeric(length=length(original_array))

rdnum <- sample(unique(original_array), length(unique(original_array)))

for ( i in  1:length(unique(original_array)))
random_numbers[original_array == i] <- rdnum[i]

random_numbers
2 2 2 2 5 5 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 6 7 7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The `table` function with `sample` comes in quite handy for this scenerio:

```
set.seed(1)

     ## ASSUMING ORIGINAL IS A VECTOR
original <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7)

     ## CREATE A TABLE OF ALL THE VALUES 
tabl <- table(original)

     ## RNG is the sample range to select from.  Assuming 1:10 in this example
RNG <- 1:10

     ## PICK VALUES RANDOMLY FROM RNG
tabl[] <- sample(RNG, length(tabl), replace=FALSE)
# note that the `names` of `tabl` will contain the values from `original`
# whereas the values of `tabl` will contain the new random value. 

     ## ASSIGN NEW VALUES 
randomNums <- original
for(i in seq(length(tabl)))
  randomNums[ original==as.numeric(names(tabl))[[i]] ] <- tabl[[i]]
```

#### Results:

```
  rbind(orig=original, rand=randomNums)

orig:  1 1 1 1  2 2  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3  4 4 4 4  5  6 6  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
rand:  3 3 3 3  4 4  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5  7 7 7 7  2  8 8  9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```